# rename redis namespace pattern on laravel?

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, redis, namespaces

It's possible to rename redis namespace pattern on laravel session storage?

[image: Laravel Redis Namespace]

Thank in advance

Comment: `prefix` variable on `config/cache.php`